# Counter resets to zero after every chunk in Laravel Excel import

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I am importing a CSV using [maatwebsite/excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) package. The CSV contains over 100 million rows, so I'm using `WithChunkReading`. I'm also logging each row insertion.

```
protected $rowCount = 0;

public function collection(Collection $rows): bool
{
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        // Insertions here

        ++$this->rowCount;
        Log::debug('Inserted row #'.$this->rowCount);
    }
    return false;
}

public function chunkSize(): int
{
    return 10;
}
```

**The problem** is that after every chunk, `$rowCount` resets to `zero`. 
 
This is what `laravel.log` outputs:

> [2020-07-13 10:06:10] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #1
> [2020-07-13 10:06:11] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #2
> [2020-07-13 10:06:11] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #3
> [2020-07-13 10:06:11] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #4
> [2020-07-13 10:06:11] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #5
> [2020-07-13 10:06:12] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #6
> [2020-07-13 10:06:12] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #7
> [2020-07-13 10:06:12] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #8
> [2020-07-13 10:06:12] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #9
> [2020-07-13 10:06:13] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #10
> [2020-07-13 10:06:16] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #1
> [2020-07-13 10:06:16] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #2
> [2020-07-13 10:06:16] local.DEBUG: Inserted row #3

I also tried using `$rowCount` by reference in a closure

```
public function collection(Collection $rows): bool
{
    $rowCount = 0;
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        // Insertions here

        $counter = function() use(&$rowCount){
            return ++$rowCount;
        };
        Log::debug('Inserted row #'.$counter->call($row));
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the result is still the same.

**Update**: I tried accessing the counter from outside the `collection` method -

```
protected $rowCount = 0;

public function collection(Collection $rows): bool
{
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        // Insertions here

        $rowCount = $this->incrementCounter();
        Log::debug('Inserted row #'.$rowCount);
    }
    return false;
}

protected function incrementCounter(){
    return ++$this->rowCount;
}

public function chunkSize(): int
{
    return 10;
}
```

This, however, did not help either. The counter still resets back.

How can I persist the value of `$rowCount` so that it does not reset back to `0` after every chunk? 
TIA!

Comment: Have you tried the `RemembersRowNumber` trait mentioned [here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html#chunk-reading)?

Comment: @Remul, "Remembering row numbers is only intended for `ToModel` imports." Unfortunately, I can't use them because I need to update the record if it already exists - using `updateOrCreate`. I can either use `ToCollection` or `OnEachRow`, neither of these work with `RemembersRowNumber`. :(

Comment: As far as I know `toModel` will just call `saveOrFail()` on the provided model, so you can either return a new model instance or a existing one which then would be updated.

Comment: So you could change your code to use `ToModel`, then use `YourModel::firstOrNew` to either retrieve the existing model or create a new model instance, fill all the attributes that you want to update and then return the model, which would either create a new record or update existing ones.

Comment: @Remul, It turns out that the trait is not available in the package yet. See the [issue I created yesterday](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/2755). I tried creating the trait manually, getting the source from their repository, but it was causing all sorts of issues - returning `int` instead of `resource` to the model function, etc. Additionally, I wouldn't want my client to have to add files manually to the vendor directory.

Comment: @[Qumber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10625611/qumber) Do you got any solution for this issue. I'm also stuck with this past 4 days. Didn't get a clue to resolve this issue.

Comment: @ManoMahe The `RemembersRowNumber` trait is now available in the package to keep track of the rows.